# How to collapse (hide) gridView in RowsFragment (show only if row focused)

Tags: java, android, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to repeat this `UI` (begin at 20sec):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba4gAUN3yHo

Something like `RowsSupportFragment`, but horizontal grid hidden for each row. Grid shown only for selected row.

How to implement this behaviour ?

I'm try to extend `ListRowPresenter` and override `onSelectLevelChanged`
But i can't switch between rows (up/down) and inside row (left/right)

```java
@Override
    protected void onSelectLevelChanged(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onSelectLevelChanged(holder);

        ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder vh = (ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder) holder;

        if (vh.isSelected()){
            vh.getGridView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            vh.getGridView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might wanna create an Android TV Activity and look into its implementation

Comment: I already did an Activity. All is well. Now the task is to customize RowsFragment (or use something else)